# Bulk email with multiple attachment using SMTP

Tags: email, smtp, attachment

I need a program that will be used to send email using SMTP from a local machine. I need to send about 2000 emails.

The emails addresses are located in a MS Excel document with unique ID numbers. The attachments are in a separate folder with unique ID numbers same as the excel folder. 
Every recipient will receive the same email with different attachment according to the ID number.

Is there any free or low cost program available out there that will achieve the goal?

If not, what is the best and quickest way to write a program like this?

**Example of MS Excel Data:**

DWEL1859    jack@bla.com

DSYD1514    caleb@bla.com

DSYD1738    jen@bla.com

DNSW2736    shown@bla.com

DPRE2510    roger@bla.com

**Example of zip file names:**

DNSW2736.zip

DPRE2510.zip

DSYD1514.zip

DSYD1738.zip

DWEL1859.zip

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [PHPMailer](http://phpmailer.worxware.com/) with couple of any DB server (i.e. MySQL) and PHP script containing some trivial logic. Write me on email (see accaunt) if you will need help within realization.

Comment: Well I managed to create a solution using c# and I achieved the goal for the purpose. But I suppose PHP can also do the job.

I must say though that the console app I created was pretty neat and sent out 2000 emails without any problem.

Comment: I wrote web service on php that was sent about 1000000 emails. PHPMailer - great solution for this purpose.